# Ubuntu и Windows

Tags: linux, windows

На компе стоит утунту 11,04. Занимает весь диск. Можно ли как нибудь поставить рядом Windows? не удаляя убунту и вообще не занимаясь перестановкой ОС?

Answer (score 4):

Поставьте винду на виртуалбокс.

Comment: Поддерживаю virtualbox

Comment: нет. виртуальная машина не в счет

Comment: тогда делайте как написал <b>mikillskegg</b><br>
PS:мой + за виртуальную машину

Comment: Чем не устраивает виртуальная машина?

Answer (score 1):

Если можно, сократить место, занимаемое убунтой на диске, и вообще выделить место под новый раздел, на котором и установить виндовс. Но потом придется восстанавливать GRUB.

Comment: PS: для сокращения места можно воспользоваться ext2resize

Answer (score 1):

gparted в руки для измененрия размеров разделов. Поставить винду после чего править GRUB

Answer (score 0):

разбей диск, и установи на другой винду